# Displaying php variables for the value in text boxes

Tags: php

I need to have users choose a task to edit from a drop down box. I need to take this value and perform a `SELECT` query to fill out a form with the results of this query. I have the drop down menu working fine. I am accurately passing the value through the `$_POST['taskID']` variable. I am loading the proper value into `$taskName`. I added the `print_r` and echos at the bottom of this as a test to make certain I was getting the proper values. I have tried using every syntax choice I have found in the forums. This would include single quotes, using echo, adding a semi colon, etc. I am using this in a `.php` file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I am using:

```html
Task Name: <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="32" value="<?= $taskName ?>" /><br /><br /> 
        <?php
        $tidHolder = $_POST['taskID'];
            include( 'inc/mice.inc.php' );
                $cxn = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $password, $database );
                $sql = "SELECT taskName FROM taskManager_tasks WHERE tid = '$tidHolder'" ;
                $sqlResult = mysqli_query( $cxn, $sql);

                if (!$sqlResult)
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlResult);
                $taskName=$row['taskName'];
                echo $tidHolder;
                print_r($_POST);
                echo $taskName;
            ?>
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
Task Name: <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="32" value="<?= $taskName ?>" />
```

needs to come *after* you get the value for `$taskName`. So put it at the end of that code block.

Comment: Please, use `htmlspecialchars()` here.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 <?= $taskName ?>
```

try

```
<?php echo $taskName ?>
```